# Check for dependency of a Qt plugin at runtime

Tags: qt, plugins, oracle-call-interface

Here's what I have: My application is statically compiled with Qt 4.5. I'm using the `qsqloci` plugin (linked statically), which loads the oracle libraries dynamically (`oci.dll`, ...).

I'd like to be able to check for the presence of the oracle DLLs and according to the result use the plugin features or not.

And the questions:

- Is that possible with the plugin linked statically?
- If not, is is possible with the plugin linked dynamically (the rest of the app still linked statically against Qt)?
- If not, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can check if a DLL is available by using `QLibrary`.

After the library had loaded, instead of starting to use `QLibrary::resolve`, you would load your plugin.

```
QLibrary lib("oci"); // QLibrary will try the platform's library suffix
if (! lib.load()) {
  qDebug() << "Library load error:" << lib.errorString();
  return;
}
// load plugin
```

You can't use `QPluginLoader` to load the plugin because you are statically linking, but you should be able to use `QLibrary`.

The [manual](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpluginloader.html#details) states:

> Note that the QPluginLoader cannot be used if your application is statically linked against Qt. In this case, you will also have to link to plugins statically. You can use QLibrary if you need to load dynamic libraries in a statically linked application.

Comment: Ok, but the plugin is loaded with the macro `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN` which by definition 'loads' the plugin at compile time. The problem is not much to detect the availability of the DLL than to dynamically 'load' the plugin.

Comment: If you want dynamic Qt plugins, you need to use a dynamic Qt library. I've edited to quote the manual.

Comment: Just to be sure; soes that mean that the plugin _has to_ be dynamically linked against Qt? Or that the plugin _can_ be statically linked against Qt but _must_ be dynamically loaded from the app?

Comment: The plugin can be statically linked or dynamically loaded, but if you want to use dynamic/runtime loading of plugins with QPluginLoader, you have to dynamically link the Qt library. Why do you need to statically link? If it is to solve a different problem, ask that and people may be able to come up with a different solution to static linking.